# How to increase post request content limit from applet

Tags: java, post, applet, http-post

From applet I am sending data to asp script by post request. This works fine until the number of characters in data written is less then 138000 but when it increases this limit then applet give 500 error. My code snippet is as below

```
URL url=new URL(baseUrl);
HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(data.length());
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", ""+(data.length()+1000));
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
out.write(data);
out.close();
```

And exception given by java is as below

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:96/makeCSV.asp
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

Please tell me how can I send large amount of data by post request from java applet.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a client side problem.  You'll most likely have to change your server configuration.

Comment: what I will have to change in server configuration, I am using IIS server, and operating system is windows server(it can be server 2003 or server 2008)